# Use column header as labels for x ticks

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

With `pgfplots`, it is possible to let the `xticklabels` be given by one column of a table. However, is it possible to import it from the table header ?

In my concrete case, I have a table with two columns "speed" and "velocity". Ideally, they should be read from the table headers instead of writing it explicitely like `yticklabels={speed,distance}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{filecontents}{test.dat}
speed distance
1 3
20 10
2 3
3 4
5 6
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ytick={1,2},yticklabels={speed,distance}]
\pgfplotstablegetcolsof{test.dat}\pgfmathsetmacro\numberofycols{\pgfplotsretval-1}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach {0,...,\numberofycols}{
\addplot+[boxplot] table[y index=#1] {test.dat};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a new style that loops over the columns of a specified table, writes the column names to a list, and then uses that list to set the y tick labels:

```
\pgfplotsset{
    yticklabels from column names/.code={
        \pgfplotstableread{#1}\loadedtable
        \def\columnnamelist{}
        \pgfplotstableforeachcolumn\loadedtable\as\col{%
            \edef\columnnamelist{\columnnamelist\col,}
        }
        \pgfplotsset{yticklabels/.expand once=\columnnamelist}
    }
}
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{filecontents}{test.dat}
speed distance
1 3
20 10
2 3
3 4
5 6
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotsset{
    yticklabels from column names/.code={
        \pgfplotstableread{#1}\loadedtable
        \def\columnnamelist{}
        \pgfplotstableforeachcolumn\loadedtable\as\col{%
            \edef\columnnamelist{\columnnamelist\col,}
        }
        \pgfplotsset{yticklabels/.expand once=\columnnamelist}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ytick={1,2}, yticklabels from column names=test.dat]
\pgfplotstablegetcolsof{test.dat}\pgfmathsetmacro\numberofycols{\pgfplotsretval-1}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach {0,...,\numberofycols}{
\addplot+[boxplot] table[y index=#1] {test.dat};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```